# How to avoid few columns in a data frame while merging data with an other data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames `df1` and `df2`.

```
df1 =
A  B  C  D
1  2  3  7
.
. 

df2 = 
A  E  F  G
1  5  4  5
.
.
```

When I usually want to merge specific columns from two data frames using `pandas` I do this:

```
import pandas as pd

df3 = pd.merge(df1[[A,B]],df2[[A,G]], on='A', how='inner')
```

However, I am interested in knowing how to avoid a few columns in a data frame and merge the rest. For example, I want to avoid the columns `C`and `D` in `df1` and columns `E`and`F` in `df2` while merging so the resultant `df3` has only `A,B,G` columns only.

It is reverse engineering. When there are few columns in each data frame it may not be useful and the first method would be enough, but while working with hundreds of columns and if any few columns are to be avoided the second approach would be helpful.

Comment: `drop`them  before merging or `reindex` the desired columns after merge, for common columns you can manipulate the `suffix` param

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `drop`:

```
df1.drop(['C','D'], axis=1).merge(df2.drop(['E','F'], axis=1), on='A')
```

Comment: Edited the question. How to add multiple columns in the drop()?

Comment: You can also drop after merging (if dataframes are not very large).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df3=df1.merge(df2, on='A',how ="inner")
df3.drop(['E,'F',C','D'], axis=1)
```

this works but this solution is inefficient so dropping before merging will be optimal.